# Awk social security number regex without lookaheads

Tags: regex, awk

I want a regex that matches social security numbers in formats XXX-XX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXX and upholds the following rules:

The first three should have 3 digits and should not be 000, 666, or between 900 and 999.
The following two should have 2 digits and it should be from 01 to 99.
The following four should have 4 digits and it should be from 0001 to 9999.

I found a regex on GeeksForGeeks that I slightly tweaked that works, but not on awk because it does not support lookaheads:
`^(?!666|000|9[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3}[-]?(?!00)[0-9]{2}[-]?(?!0{4})[0-9]{4}$`

Is there a way I can tweak this regex to still uphold social security number logic without lookaheads?

https://regex101.com/r/C9kFbI/2

I have my regex here with some testcases separated by what should pass and what should fail.

This is what my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")";
}
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if(match($i, /^(?!666|000|9[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3}[-]?(?!00)[0-9]{2}[-]?(?!0{4})[0-9]{4}$/)) {
            print $i;
        }
    }
}

END {print "DONE"}
```

Comment: pleae update the question with a sample set of data (2-4 lines, 3-4 fields per line should suffice) from your input file making sure to include matching and non-matching ssn's; also include the expected output (corresponding to the samlpe input)

Comment: just to be clear: we should not have to follow a link to an external page and then ascertain what parts of that external page represent the sample input and/or the expected output; it gets more confusing when you consider your `awk` code seems to imply you're dealing with a csv-formatted file with multiple fields that could contain a ssn, while that external page contains nothing that looks like a set of csv-formatted data; you improve the chances of getting a working solution if you include all pertinent details (including data) in the question

Comment: The regexp you have doesn't work even with a tool that'd support that regexp style (PCRE?) since it'd accept `111-223333` or `11122-3333` as valid SSNs despite neither of them looking like `XXX-XX-XXXX` or `XXXXXXXXX`. There may be other issues with it too but I expect it's too convoluted for most people to understand it's nuances (certainly is for me!) so you probably wouldn't find out what those issues are until they show up in your real data some day down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk (which you're already using for `FPAT`) for the 3rd arg to `match()` and per your stated requirements:

> I want a regex that matches social security numbers in formats
> XXX-XX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXX
> ...
> The first three should have 3 digits
> ...
> The following two should have 2 digits
> ...
> The following four should have 4 digits

```
match($i,/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})$/,a) ||
match($i,/^([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/,a)
```

I'm using 2 separate regexps there as `/^([0-9]{3})-?([0-9]{2})-?([0-9]{4})$/` would match `111-223333` or `11122-3333`, neither of which look like `XXX-XX-XXXX` or `XXXXXXXXX`.

> The first three should ... not be 000, 666, or between 900 and 999.

```
(a[1] != 0) && (a[1] != 666) && (a[1] < 900)
```

> The following two should ... be from 01 to 99.

```
(a[2] != 0)
```

> The following four should ... be from 0001 to
> 9999.

```
(a[3] != 0)
```

Then put it all together to get:

```
( match($i,/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})$/,a) ||
  match($i,/^([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/,a) ) &&
(a[1] != 0) && (a[1] != 666) && (a[1] < 900) && (a[2] != 0) && (a[3] != 0)
```

Regarding trying to do the validation with a single regexp just bear in mind [this quote](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

The easy fix is to accept all numbers which match the base pattern and add a second check for the matches which should be rejected.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")" }
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if(match($i, /^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}$/))
            if(!match($i, /^(666|000|9[0-9]{2}) && !match($i, /^[0-9]{3}-?00/) && !match($i, /0{4}$/))
                print $i
}
# I would comment this out
END {print "DONE"}
```

Comment: No big deal but `|9[0-9]{2}` could just be `|9` alone since the preceding regexp in the `match()` guarantees its followed by 2 digits. Similarly `/^[0-9]{3}` could be `/^.{3}` since the `match()` guarantees digits. The match() regexp would treat `111-223333` or `11122-3333` as if it were a valid SSN as defined by the OP though (XXX-XX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXX).

Answer (score 1):

Breaking your first rule apart does the trick:

> The first three should have 3 digits and should not be 000, 666, or between 900 and 999.

We need to consider two special cases whenever the string starts with 0 or 6 and not allow it as the second or third character and also haver a rule allowing any second/third digits in case it begins with by 1 to 5 or 7 or 8.

^(0[1-9]\d|0\d[1-9]|6[0-57-9]\d|6\d[0-57-9]|[1-57-8]\d\d)-\d{2}-\d{4}$

This link has test cases covering the cases starting with 6.

https://regex101.com/r/A4V19c/1

Comment: There is no awk or any mandatory POSIX tool that'd recognize `\d` as meaning a digit. `regex101` verifies that a regexp does something specific on that site, that doesn't mean that regexp will do the same thing in any command-line tool.

Comment: \d can be easily replaced by [0-9] which is pretty standard.

Comment: Then why not do so in your answer so that anyone who tries to use it doesn't have to do so?

Comment: This is the answer. Question asks for a single regex.

Comment: @EdMorton Anyone doing this in Awk should do it your way. This answer is useful for future visitors who are looking for a regex to match these SSNs in some other context, and don't want to (or cannot) use the weird non-regex features.

Comment: @Kaz that's fine, I'm just suggesting the poster use a portable construct `[0-9]` instead of `\d` so anyone coming across this in future trying to use that regexp in awk, sed, grep, bash, etc. don't waste their time trying to figure out why it doesn't work. It won't be obvious to people who aren't very familiar with regexps that `\d` is the problem.

Comment: @Kaz actually, this isn't the answer. In the regex101 demo linked from this answer the regexp doesn't match `001341343` which is included in the set of numbers at the top of the example that should match. It seems like it requires `-`s in the regexp and so wouldn't match the OPs `XXXXXXXXX` use case. You can't just make the `-`s individually optional or then it'd undesirably match `XXX-XXXXXX` or `XXXXX-XXXX`.

Comment: It also doesn't address the OPs criteria for the 2nd or 3rd block of digits so it'd undesirably accept the 2nd block of digits being `00` or the 3rd block being `0000` as you can also see in the example linked from this answer where it matches `888-00-1785` and `888-04-0000`. That's the "beauty" of using a single regexp - even mid-length ones are so convoluted you can't obviously see if they actually satisfy the requirements or not and you have to hope your testing covers all use cases to identify anything it misses. A single regexp to actually do what the OP requested would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

General rules:

- must be of format `###-##-####` or `#########`; do not accept `###-######` or `#####-####`
- must not start with `000`, `666` or `9`
- 4th/5th digits must not be `00`
- last 4 digits must not be `0000`

One `awk` idea for the `for` loop:

```
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ( $i ~ /^([0-9]{9}|[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})$/ && ! ( $i ~ /^000|^666|^9|^...-?00|0000$/ ) ) {

             #   ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ validate format as ######### or ###-##-####
             #                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ filter out unwanted data sets

          print $i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge volumes to process but also don't mind mixing `regex` with other filtering code, then you can save some upfront time by checking

```
index("_" $0, "_666") + index($0 "=", "0000=") < (($0 < "001#") < ($0 < "9#"))
```

This handles the filtering criteria for first 3 digits by using vanilla (and low-cost) string ops before utilizing the full `regex` checker for the remaining portions. Prefixing the string with `"_"` or suffixing it with `"="` are the vanilla string ops equivalent of enforcing regex anchors of head (`/^.../`) and (`/...$/)`, but at a much lower cost.

It rapidly kills off the obvious cases but doesn't confirm they're all in fact numerical digits.